# Как отцентрировать форму?

Tags: css, jquery

Сделал форму которая появляется по click с разных кнопок но вот не задача, если к примеру кликнули по кнопке которая в самом низу страницы то форма всплывает в самом верху ...

**Как можно сделать без дублирования самой формы всплытие там где кликнули ?**

```js
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  $(".form").show();
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.form {
  width: 375px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 120px #000;
  display: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  Форма обращения
  <form action="">
    <p>Ваше Имя <input type="text"></p>
    <p>Ваше Фамилия <input type="text"></p>
    <p>
      М<input type="radio" name="a"> Ж
      <input type="radio" name="a">
    </p>
    <p>
      Ваше сообщение
      <textarea name="" id="" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>
</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iure esse quae iusto provident suscipit sequi similique dolore debitis deserunt illo delectus rerum rem fugit earum. Libero, tempore saepe.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">

<button class="button">Открыть форму</button>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sunt autem perferendis excepturi repellendus aliquid vero maxime magni odit facere iusto molestias, cupiditate magnam iure quo blanditiis vel. Sapiente, nostrum.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iure esse quae iusto provident suscipit sequi similique dolore debitis deserunt illo delectus rerum rem fugit earum. Libero, tempore saepe.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iure esse quae iusto provident suscipit sequi similique dolore debitis deserunt illo delectus rerum rem fugit earum. Libero, tempore saepe.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">
<button class="button">Открыть форму</button>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iure esse quae iusto provident suscipit sequi similique dolore debitis deserunt illo delectus rerum rem fugit earum. Libero, tempore saepe.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iure esse quae iusto provident suscipit sequi similique dolore debitis deserunt illo delectus rerum rem fugit earum. Libero, tempore saepe.
</p>
<button class="button">Открыть форму</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Другими словами что бы она всегда была в поле видимости**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не менял, всего лишь подменил `position: absolute;` на `position: fixed;`

Если форма собирается быть длинной, внутри неё дополнительно можно добавить скролл, через `overflow: scroll`, ограничив высоту, например через `height: 100vh` (vh процентно зависит от высоты текущего окна)

```js
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  $(".form").show();
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.form {
  width: 375px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 120px #000;
  display: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  Форма обращения
  <form action="">
    <p>Ваше Имя <input type="text"></p>
    <p>Ваше Фамилия <input type="text"></p>
    <p>
      М<input type="radio" name="a"> Ж
      <input type="radio" name="a">
    </p>
    <p>
      Ваше сообщение
      <textarea name="" id="" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>
</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iure esse quae iusto provident suscipit sequi similique dolore debitis deserunt illo delectus rerum rem fugit earum. Libero, tempore saepe.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">

<button class="button">Открыть форму</button>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos sunt autem perferendis excepturi repellendus aliquid vero maxime magni odit facere iusto molestias, cupiditate magnam iure quo blanditiis vel. Sapiente, nostrum.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iure esse quae iusto provident suscipit sequi similique dolore debitis deserunt illo delectus rerum rem fugit earum. Libero, tempore saepe.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iure esse quae iusto provident suscipit sequi similique dolore debitis deserunt illo delectus rerum rem fugit earum. Libero, tempore saepe.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">
<button class="button">Открыть форму</button>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iure esse quae iusto provident suscipit sequi similique dolore debitis deserunt illo delectus rerum rem fugit earum. Libero, tempore saepe.
</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, cum iure esse quae iusto provident suscipit sequi similique dolore debitis deserunt illo delectus rerum rem fugit earum. Libero, tempore saepe.
</p>
<button class="button">Открыть форму</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо ...мне спать надо чаще ...

Answer (score 2):

Я использую такую центровку:

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(50vw, 50vh) 
             translate(-50%, -50%) 
             rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>
<img class="center" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1my.png?s=128">
```